# Is there any way in mongo DB to get the inner value of json data?

Tags: mongodb

My Json data is this, (This what I store in the mongo DB)

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : "e9925559-4830-476f-8d6a-789ade4ec51c",
    "account_user_id" : "sahaal",
    "account_number" : "23423",
    "Job Profile" : {
        "externalid" : "250250ICM",
        "bgcpackagetype" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "C19902",
                "value" : "1800 - Happy Path Background Check",
                "formattedvalue" : "1800 - Happy Path Background Check"
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "C19900",
                "value" : "2112 - Esteem Validation Package",
                "formattedvalue" : "2112 - Esteem Validation Package"
            }
        ],
        "links" : [ 
            {
                "title" : "The current profile being viewed.",
                "rel" : "self",
                "url" : "https://api.icims.com/customers/2187/jobs/2015"
            }
        ],
        "jobid" : "2013-2015"
    },
    "request" : {
        "newStatus" : "9782",
        "oldStatus" : "1752",
        "customerId" : "1234",
        "jobId" : "1242",
        "userId" : "3",
        "personId" : "1364",
        "links" : [ 
            {
                "title" : "Applicant Workflow",
                "rel" : "applicantWorkflow",
                "url" : "https://api.icims.com/customers/1234/applicantworkflows/2203"
            }, 
            {
                "title" : "Job Profile",
                "rel" : "job",
                "url" : "https://api.icims.com/customers/2187/jobs/2015"
            }, 
            {
                "title" : "Person Profile",
                "rel" : "person",
                "url" : "https://api.icims.com/customers/2187/people/7260"
            }, 
            {
                "title" : "Posting User",
                "rel" : "user",
                "url" : "https://api.icims.com/customers/2187/people/7425"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Candidate Profile" : {
        "workexperience" : [ 
            {
                "workdescription" : "Investigated the effects on body weight and bone growth of replacement injections of thyroid hormone and drugs that inhibit thyroid hormone production * Performed IM injections in chickens * Ran 80 blood samples through gas chromatograph to check T1 levels * Prepared bone growth media for 8 sets of experiments",
                "entry" : 47964,
                "workstartdate" : "2011-01-01",
                "workenddate" : "2011-06-01",
                "worktitle" : "Research Assistant",
                "workemployer" : "UC Riverside"
            }, 
            {
                "workcity" : "Pomona",
                "workdescription" : "Worked closely with staff performing tasks such as escorting patients, preparing charts, stocking rooms with supplies, running errands, answering phones, and light clerical tasks * Provided patient care by taking vital signs, weighing patients, answering call lights and providing psychosocial support for patients * Learned basics of telemetry",
                "entry" : 47965,
                "workstartdate" : "2009-05-01",
                "workcountry" : {
                    "id" : "D41001",
                    "value" : "United States",
                    "abbrev" : "US"
                },
                "workenddate" : "2011-06-01",
                "worktitle" : "Intern",
                "workstate" : {
                    "id" : "D41001008",
                    "value" : "California",
                    "abbrev" : "CA"
                },
                "workemployer" : "Pomona Valley Hospital Medical Center"
            }
        ],
        "licensecertification" : [ 
            {
                "stateissued" : {
                    "id" : "D41001008",
                    "value" : "United States - California",
                    "formattedvalue" : "United States - California"
                },
                "entry" : 48064,
                "licensecertstatus" : {
                    "id" : "D37002036001",
                    "value" : "Current",
                    "formattedvalue" : "Current"
                },
                "licensenumber" : "D8257463",
                "licensetype" : "Drivers License"
            }
        ],
        "email" : "ravi.sathish@fadv.com",
        "birthdate" : "1970-01-01",
        "lastname" : "Landis",
        "links" : [ 
            {
                "title" : "The current profile being viewed.",
                "rel" : "self",
                "url" : "https://api.icims.com/customers/2187/people/7260"
            }
        ],
        "firstname" : "Job",
        "addresses" : [ 
            {
                "addresstype" : {
                    "id" : "D84002",
                    "value" : "Home",
                    "formattedvalue" : "Home"
                },
                "addresscountry" : {
                    "id" : "D41001",
                    "value" : "United States",
                    "abbrev" : "US"
                },
                "addresszip" : "92521",
                "addressstreet1" : "1234 Street Name",
                "entry" : 3403,
                "addressstate" : {
                    "id" : "D41001008",
                    "value" : "California",
                    "abbrev" : "CA"
                },
                "addresscity" : "Riverside"
            }
        ],
        "education" : [ 
            {
                "degree" : {
                    "id" : "C19850",
                    "value" : "B.S",
                    "formattedvalue" : "B.S"
                },
                "school" : {
                    "id" : "C19849",
                    "value" : "University of California",
                    "formattedvalue" : "University of California"
                },
                "entry" : 289,
                "major" : {
                    "id" : "C19852",
                    "value" : "Biological Sciences",
                    "formattedvalue" : "Biological Sciences"
                }
            }
        ],
        "phones" : [ 
            {
                "phonetype" : {
                    "id" : "D83002",
                    "value" : "Home",
                    "formattedvalue" : "Home"
                },
                "phonenumber" : "555-555-5555",
                "entry" : 4823
            }, 
            {
                "phonetype" : {
                    "id" : "D83003",
                    "value" : "Fax",
                    "formattedvalue" : "Fax"
                },
                "phonenumber" : "666-555-6666",
                "entry" : 4829
            }
        ]
    },
    "account_password" : "Pass12!$",
    "Recruiter Profile" : {
        "email" : "Harry@fadv.com",
        "lastname" : "HiringManager",
        "links" : [ 
            {
                "title" : "The current profile being viewed.",
                "rel" : "self",
                "url" : "https://api.icims.com/customers/2187/people/7171"
            }
        ],
        "firstname" : "Harry"
    }
}
```

Search result should only display,

```
"links" : [ 
                {
                    "title" : "Applicant Workflow",
                    "rel" : "applicantWorkflow",
                    "url" : "https://api.icims.com/customers/1234/applicantworkflows/2203"
                }, 
                {
                    "title" : "Job Profile",
                    "rel" : "job",
                    "url" : "https://api.icims.com/customers/2187/jobs/2015"
                }, 
                {
                    "title" : "Person Profile",
                    "rel" : "person",
                    "url" : "https://api.icims.com/customers/2187/people/7260"
                }, 
                {
                    "title" : "Posting User",
                    "rel" : "user",
                    "url" : "https://api.icims.com/customers/2187/people/7425"
                }
            ]
```

**EDIT :-**

My need is, I need the `url` of "title" = "Person Profile". As it can be in any location so I can say third url

Comment: Do you want a json document only containing the links field or do you want to lose the curly braces around it too?

Comment: Curly braces are required, because result should be proper json format

Comment: edited that in the question

Comment: There are some **links** in the document. Do you mean any **links** is possible if the **title** = "Person Profile"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get array subdocuments by dot notation so the projection `"request.links":1,_id:0` in

```
db.collection.find({query},{"request.links":1,_id:0})
```

should do the trick.

---

After edited Question:

For the edited question you will need an aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [{$match: {Your document query}},
                          {$unwind: "$request.links"},
                          {$match: {"request.links.title":"Person Profile"}},
                          {$project: {_id : 0, link : "$request.links.url"}}])
```

Stepwise explanation:

1. First `$match` finds your document (same as in find)
2. `$unwind` makes a single document for each array element
3. Second `$match` searches for the link with your title
4. `$project` shows only the link

Comment: I edited the question, can you please give me the answer for that also ?

Comment: @Sahal The aggregation should now work it had some typos